# How to copy a SQL table to another server with index and keys?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to copy 2 tables from one server to another with the primary key, data and index.

***Method 1:***
I have tried with import/export wizard and exported data, also `edited the script to have primary key and identity` and `checked the insert identity checkbox before execution`.

***Method 2:***
Generated script for those 2 tables with `Types of data to script - Schema and data`  and `Script Indexes - True`

But in both of these method, i am losing the identity functionality in the new table. When I do a right click on the new table and select Design option, the ***Identity Specification*** is stated as ***NO*** but in the old table it is staed as YES.

Is there any other method to copy a table with this identity functionality?

Comment: in SSMS's object explorer right click the table -> script table as -> create To-> clipboard. Paste to a new query window connected to the other server. Note: you might need to change the `USE` statement in the database name is different. Then copy the data between the tables.

Comment: @ZoharPeled :  This is creating only the table not copying the data, even then Identity specification is "No". I want to copy the data also.

Comment: Are you sure your original table has an identity column? From what I know, both SSIS and SSMS's script table as have no problem with identity columns. (BTW, Note I've ended my last comment with "Then copy the data...")

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yeah, you are right. The Identity Specification is Now 'Yes' for the newly created table. But yesterday when i checked immediately, it was 'No'. Is there any other method which copies the table completely with data, index and key?

Comment: SSIS Should do the trick. It's been in use for a very long time now and I doubt you'll find unknown bugs in it. Somewhere along the lines you've probably made a mistake somewhere and couldn't see it. Don't feel bad about it, that happens to us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is a bug in `Microsoft SSMS`. With your method 1 `SSMS 2016` still executes the standard `CREATE TABLE` query in the background, although you edit it in the wizard. My recommendation is that you download and install the latest `SSMS` version. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) is the link to it. After that you can use your method 1 without problems and it will work without problems.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. With SSMS 2018, my first method of editing the script while exporting the data works fine.